# JSF - primefaces 3.5 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "" when rendering

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I get this error when I downgrade my application from primefaces 4.0 to 3.5...

I have removed all references to "()" in the xhtmls... but it doesn't work
(example: #{myBean.myMethod()} =>  #{myBean.myMethod}  )

```
09:59:20,253 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ""
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:570) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:245) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:90) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:200) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:75) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:50) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:172) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:101) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:43) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

09:59:20,262 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/moduloMedicos].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) Servlet.service() para servlet Faces Servlet lanzó excepción: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ""
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:570) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:245) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:90) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:200) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:75) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:50) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:172) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:101) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:43) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

in the pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

my view files are too large to be copied here... but they contain:
selectoneMenu, buttons, tables: with buttons inside
dialogs: with selectoneMenu, buttons, tables

Thank you all in advance!

SOLUTION

All the updates must have this structure:

update=":identifier"
update=":id1,:id2,:id3,@form,@this"

Comment: Exception says you've somewhere a `<p:commandButton update="">` with empty string (which in turn is inside a `<p:dialog>`).

Comment: all my update are filled like  update=":id" update="id1 id2 id3" update="@form id5"

Comment: I was just translating the exception to layman's terms so you can naildown the root cause. Usually, exceptions don't lie.